# Mathematica, efficient way to compare dates

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list like this:

```
{{2002, 4, 10}, 9.61}, {{2002, 4, 11}, 9.53}, {{2002, 4, 12}, 9.58},
```

I need to lookup this list to find the exact match of date, if there is no match, I'll have the next available date in the list, here is my code:

```
Select[history, DateDifference[#[[1]], {2012, 3, 17}] <= 0 &, 1]
```

but it's a lot slower than just looking for exact match, is there a faster way to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, this is a good question!  You can consider asking Mathematica-related questions on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) as well.  It's likely that you'll get answers faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
finddate[data:{{{_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}, _}..}, 
   date:{_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}] := 
  First[Extract[data, (Position[#1, First[Nearest[#1, AbsoluteTime[date]]]] & )[
     AbsoluteTime/@ data[[All,1]]]]]
```

will do what you want.
E.g.,

```
finddate[{{{2002, 4, 10}, 9.61}, {{2002, 4, 11}, 9.53}, {{2002, 4, 12}, 9.58}}, 
{2012, 3, 17}]
```

gives {{2002, 4, 12}, 9.58}

It seems to be reasonably fast ( half a second for 10^5 dates ).

Answer (score 6):

It is true that `DateDifference` is rather slow.  This can be worked around by converting all dates to "absolute times", which in Mathematica means the number of seconds elapsed since 1900 January 1.

Here's an example.  This is the data:

```
data = {AbsoluteTime[#1], #2} & @@@ 
   FinancialData["GOOG", {{2010, 1, 1}, {2011, 1, 1}}];
```

We're looking for this date or the next one if this is not available:

```
date = AbsoluteTime[{2010, 8, 1}]
```

One way to retrieve it is:

```
dt[[1 + LengthWhile[dt[[All, 1]], # < date &]]]
```

You'll find other methods, including an already implemented binary search, [in the answers to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/finding-elements-in-a-sorted-list).

Answer (score 2):

Could you / would it be faster for you to write a binary search, assuming that your history is ordered?

That should give you the date in log(n) comparisons, which is way better than the linear filter you appear to be using now.
If will give you the date, if it exists, or if the date does not exist, it will give you the point where you should insert the new date.

Comment: Thank you zebediah49 for kindly helping a newbie instead of voting him down! I checked BinarySearch, it seems promising but I encounter this problem, I tried with this:
BinarySearch[history, {2012, 3, 15}, #[[1]] &]
it seems BinarySearch doesn't treat {2012, 3, 15} as one item, so the search fails, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest thing for many accesses into the same dataset is to create an interpolation function based on the AbsoluteTime[] of the date and the value.  If the default swings the wrong way, you can negate all the "seconds" and it'll swing that way.